# InfiniteScroll (react-infinite-scroll-component) leads to the bottom of the page when new data populates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using InfiniteScroll (react-infinite-scroll-component). This is in reverse order. But it leads to the bottom of the page whenever I load new data using my API. This is my code:

```
<div
     id="scrollableDiv"
     style={{
       flex: 1,
       overflow: "auto",
       display: "flex",
       flexDirection: "column-reverse",
     }}
   >
     <InfiniteScroll
       dataLength={messageGroups.length}
       onScroll={e => {
         e.preventDefault();
         const scrollHeight = e.target.scrollHeight;
         const varHeight = e.target.scrollTop - e.target.clientHeight;
         console.log("varHeight", varHeight);
         if (scrollHeight + varHeight < 1) {
           onFetchPreviousMessages();
         }
       }}
       style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column-reverse" }} //To put endMessage and loader to the top.
       id="scrollableDiv"
       ref={scrollableDiv}
       scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
     />
     <div ref={messageRef} />
     {!messageGroups.length && composeType === "help" && (
       <ExplorerLargeInfoBlock
         icon={<FaLifeRing />}
         header="Help Request"
         message="Need help? Send us a message below and someone on the project team will get back to you shortly."
       />
     )}
     {messageGroups.map(renderMessageGroup)}
</div>

I referred some posts where the div was being used, but not sure how to access the div.current in my case.

onFetchPreviousMessages is simply calling data API to fetch new data
```

Comment: provide fetch attribute in infiniteScroller   <InfiniteScroll  fetch ={ FetchApi() }  /> may be this work

Comment: fetch prop is invoking the entire data in 1 go. ie it invokes FetchAPi() in the very first load.

Answer (score 0):

To access the div.current in your case, you can use the `useRef` hook to create a reference to the scrollableDiv. Then, you can access the current property to get the underlying DOM element and manipulate its scroll behavior.

```
import { useRef } from "react";

const scrollableDiv = useRef(null);

<InfiniteScroll
  dataLength={messageGroups.length}
  next={onFetchPreviousMessages} // Use 'next' prop instead of 'onScroll'
  hasMore={true} // Assuming you have more data to load
  inverse={true} // Set this to true for reverse order
  loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>} // Optional: You can add a loading indicator
  scrollableTarget={scrollableDiv.current} // Pass the DOM element as the scrollable target
>
  {/* Render your message items here */}
</InfiniteScroll>
```

````
 const onFetchPreviousMessages = async () => {
  // Fetch your data here and update the messageGroups state
  // For example: const newData = await fetchData();
  // setMessageGroups([...newData, ...messageGroups]);

  // After adding new data, scroll back to the top
  scrollableDiv.current.scrollTop = 0;
};```
````

Comment: Can you share any reference code?

Comment: I have added the code. Hope it wokrs

Comment: I tried using next but it fetches data in 1 go that is causing issue, I only want data when I reach to the top of the window to save API calls,

Comment: Second I want to stay at the position where last data was present, new messages (older messages in this case) will come at the top like we have in slack

Comment: Tries this code, scrollableDiv.current.scrollTop = 0; gives Cannot set properties of null (setting 'scrollTop')

Comment: using hasMore and next instead of onScroll works but the problem of reaching the bottom persists.

Comment: scrollableDiv.current.scrollTop = 0 is not a property that is the problem